# How to draw a rgba circle with low opacity with center exactly at given X and Y dementions

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, drawing, draw

I am collecting click position (PageY and PageX) with script:

```
//heatmap
var hitMap = [];
function hitMapF(){
    $('body').click(function(zdarzenie){
        hitMap.push(zdarzenie.pageX +", "+ zdarzenie.pageY);
        console.log(hitMap);
    });
}

hitMapF();
```

each click action and to an array next positions like this:
First click:

```
["335, 161"]
```

and another click:

```
["335, 161", "190, 318"]
```

and another click:

```
["335, 161", "190, 318", "212, 542"]
```

and another click:

```
["335, 161", "190, 318", "212, 542", "144, 736"]
```

and so on ...

I would like to use those demensions (PageY and PageX) from hitMap array  as a center to draw a low opacity circle something like: rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.01) with width and height lets say 100 px;

Eventualy it would produce a basic hitmap for users interation. Any idea how to compleate this drawing with js/JQuery ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.pop` to set `left` , `top` of "hit" from last entry at `hitMap`

```js
//heatmap
var hitMap = [];

function hitMapF() {
  $("body").click(function(zdarzenie) {
    hitMap.push(zdarzenie.pageX + ", " + zdarzenie.pageY);
    var hit = hitMap.pop().split(",");
    console.log(hit[0])
    $("<div>", {
      css: {
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        background: "rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.01)",
        position: "absolute",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        border: "1px dotted #000",
        // subtract half of "circle" `width` from `left`, `top` properties
        left: hit[0] - 50 + "px",
        top: hit[1] - 50 + "px"
      }
    }).appendTo(this);
  });
}

hitMapF();
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```